# How to get root directory of Virtual Application or Virtual Dir in IIS7?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I try to use  tag in html which run on client side only.

In my IIS7 has a virtual application call "testsite". I must call "localhost/testsite" to access this site.

assume that, I have 1 image in "testsite/images" and I wanna get image from root path.

for example:

```
<img src="/image/image1.jpg" />
```

But the path of image that show in browser is "localhost/image" it should be "localhost/testsite/image". ?

What should I do? How to config an IIS7 to make them see a virtual application to be a root dir of that website?

Additional: Suppose that my HTML is in database and it has a lot of

```
<img src=/image/[imagename]>
```

And I display this text by adding it to Text property of  control, so it cannot use an runat="server" in img tag.

What is the best solution to replace an src property of img tag in my database and display in it ASP.Net page.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
<img src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>/image/image1.jpg" />
```

(assuming your using ASP.NET)

Comment: You need an extra `/` after the `<%%>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `~/` to point to the root of a web application. This will only work on serverside controls - so you will need to change your image tag to:

```
<img src="~/image/image.jpg" runat="server" />
```

Alternatively, simply output the value in the attribute:

```
<img src="<%:Page.ResolveUrl("~/")%>image/image.jpg" />
```

---

Update:

Since you are outputting within a literal control, you can simply use `Page.ResolveUrl("~/")` when setting the `Text` property of the control, similar to the alternative I have shown.

Comment: How can I use <img src="~/image/image.jpg" runat="server" /> in <asp:Literal> Control. because my html is in database and I use Literal to display that html.

Comment: @Noppol Pilukruangdet - You can't. You really should have added this "detail" to your question (that you are outputting with a literal control). Answer updated with solution.

Comment: I use Literal control to display the whole HTML that has a lot of <img> tags. I cannot replace Page.ResolveUrl to Text property using Code Behind.

Comment: @Noppol Pilukruangdet - Looks like you need to rethink your design. Doesn't sound modular or [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) at all.

Comment: `<%:` ? using **:** separator ?

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you are using HTML  tag, a cleaner approach would be to use base tag in the head section of the page.Thus you will not be required to repeat server code in each html tag.

`<base href="<%= Context.Items["baseURL"] %>" />` , i am reading this from web.config.

or `<base href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>" />`

Now you can simple use `<img src="/image/image1.jpg" />`

I doubt `Page.ResolveUrl("~/")` will work when website is hosted inside a sub-directory.